# Finding unique entries, using a list. Python

Tags: python

I am using grok learning and I can't seem to get passed this problem. You need to make a program program where you can enter one word at a time, and be told how many unique words you have entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop asking for more words when you enter a blank line.

This is my current code:

```
words = []
word = input("Word: ")
while word != '': 
    words.append(word)
    word = input("Word: ")
print('You know', len(words), 'unique word(s)!')
```

It counts the amount of words you enter but I can't figure out how to make it check it the word is unique. Here are the desired outputs:

```
Word: Chat
Word: Chien
Word: Chat
Word: Escargot
Word: 
You know 3 unique word(s)!
```

Here is another:

```
Word: Katze
Word: Hund
Word: Maus
Word: Papagei
Word: Schlange
Word: 
You know 5 unique word(s)!
```

Comment: Use a set, not a list.

Comment: Please go on, I really need help

Comment: I think reading about [what a set is](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) would be illuminating.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> words = ['Chat', 'Chien', 'Chat', 'Escargot']
>>> set(words)
set(['Chien', 'Escargot', 'Chat'])
>>> "You know " + str(len(set(words))) + " unique word(s)!"
'You know 3 unique word(s)!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set if you do not want to store duplicates.

```
words = set() #initialize a set
word = input("Word: ")
while word != '': 
    words.append(word)
    word = input("Word: ")
print('You know', len(words), 'unique word(s)!')
```

If you want to store all the elements irrespective of duplicates, use a list
If you want to find unique elements inside a list, do this:

```
myset = set(words) #Now, myset has unique elements
print('You know', len(myset), 'unique word(s)!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you should have learnt by that point in the course, you can use an `if` statement to check if the word you're looking at is already in the `words` list, and only add it if it is not already in the list:

```
words = []
word = input("Word: ")
while word != '':
  if word not in words:
    words.append(word)
  word = input("Word: ")
print('You know', len(words), 'unique word(s)!')
```

You'll learn more about sets (which are a more efficient way to solve this question) later in the course.